# Moved site from IIS 7.5 to IIS 10 and have problem with json strings

Tags: asp.net

The JSON string returned on the old server was complete and on the new server it is truncated early.

If I remove the £ symbol from the response it now works again so I believe it is a code page issue.

Any pointers on how to set it in IIS? There is code in place as well.

Thanks

EDIT, I found the culprit,  in the string sent to the client if I remove the £ symbol it comes through.